# How do I sort by decimal with simple SQL code? (Order by statement, SQLite)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have the following short SQL code and I'm completely stuck.

```
SELECT Purchases_FULL_LOCKED.Purchase_Price, 
Customers_Details_FULL_LOCKED.first_name, 
Customers_Details_FULL_LOCKED.last_name
FROM Purchases_FULL_LOCKED
LEFT JOIN Customers_Details_FULL_LOCKED ON Purchases_FULL_LOCKED.Cust_ID = 
Customers_Details_FULL_LOCKED.customer_id
WHERE Customers_Details_FULL_LOCKED.first_name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Purchases_FULL_LOCKED.Purchase_Price desc;
```

What it basically does is returns the price that a user has paid for an item and their full name, where the values are not null of course.

However, when I order it by descending (as i need to find out the top 50 spenders) the value 99.99 is apparently the most, where there are values such as 149.99 that are way down on the list.

I am sorry if this is a poorly structured question, I am new here and new to SQL, but any sort of help would be amazing.

Output Example:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxCK5.png)

Comment: What _type_ is the `Purchase_Price` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that maybe your `Purchase_Price` column is currently text, and so it is sorting as text, which is not necessarily in numerical order.  Try casting to decimal and then sorting on this column:

```
ORDER BY
    CAST(Purchases_FULL_LOCKED.Purchase_Price AS decimal) DESC;
```

Here is the full query:

```
SELECT
    p.Purchase_Price, 
    c.first_name, 
    c.last_name
FROM Purchases_FULL_LOCKED p
LEFT JOIN Customers_Details_FULL_LOCKED c
    ON p.Cust_ID = c.customer_id
WHERE
    c.first_name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    CAST(p.Purchase_Price AS decimal) DESC;
```

I introduced table aliases, which make the query much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the value is stored as a number.  The simplest method is to convert the value to a number:

```
order by Purchases_FULL_LOCKED.Purchase_Price + 0 desc
```